# What is the type of these caps?

Tags: capacitor, amplifier

I'm busy repairing a guitar amp from '79 and stumbled upon these. They look like resistors, but they are definitely caps. I confirmed that with the PCB schematics and by measuring the ones with larger values, but I don't have the equipment to measure the ones in the pF range (e.g. the one in the middle should be 470pF). So I thought about replacing them, just in case. From what I found via Google, I suppose I can use ceramic disc caps as replacement. Is that correct? And is there a way to determine their maximum voltage rating?

Edit: Not sure if I may post the complete schematics, so I added images of the areas around the caps in question. The ones on the photo are C6, C8 and C5.

[image: unknown caps]
[image: schematics]
[image: pcb layout]

Comment: Showing the schematic would help.

Comment: Are you reeeeeeeeaaaaaaaally sure those are caps? Did you unsolder one and check with a multimeter? They might also be inductors as well.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: added images of it.

Comment: @AndrejaKo yup, I did.

Comment: Is the positive rail 18V?

Comment: In that range they have to ceramics...but they sure look like resisters.  In any case, I see no reason to replace them.  Ceramics, like diamonds, are forever.

Comment: the rails are +42V and -42V

Comment: @RobertEndl They sure do... I tried to measure them like a resistor before I got the schematics. It's only a few caps, so I don't mind replacing them to be on the safe side.

Comment: Can you add a picture showing more area ... maybe 5 times more?... those look like resistors. it's possible the circuit is wrong...

Comment: @Spoon I am certain that these are caps. I have desoldered some of the same type and measured them with a function generator and an oscilloscope and also with my DMM. They behave like caps, not resistors.

Comment: No reason to replace them, ceramics don't age (mostly).  Aluminums age, replace those.  The colors seem to agree with the  schematic values.  The 10 pF part is brown-black-black.  That must mean something.

Comment: @RobertEndl what did you use to calculate the value? I searched for a capacitor color code calculator, but those I found lacked silver and/or gold as used for the 470pF.

Comment: What is up with C7 in that schematic?  It looks the wrong way around to me.

Comment: @Wossname I had the same impression but it is mounted as on the schematics and the unit used to work, so I suppose there's a reason for that...

Comment: nice camera....close up

Comment: @Naz iPad with custom made lens

Comment: Tox...I used the resister colors.  The 10 pF is obvious.  The silver & gold, I don't know what those mean.  The 470 is turned around, but that doesn't matter and the colors still work.  So...the capacitors story seems to work, even if they do look like resisters.

Comment: I checked the three caps against different color codes I found online. And for every system I have at least one cap that doesn't fit in. Maybe someone already replaced one of them with one that uses a different color coding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're just axial ceramic capacitors. They used to be quite popular and I've used them in some designs, some (many) years ago.

You can replace them with (preferably) NP0 or X7R (if you can't get NP0 in the right value and voltage rating) ceramic capacitors. Axial leaded parts are still available from disties, though without the nifty color codes.

But if they're not shorted they're probably fine and I would suggest **not** messing with them.

Comment: That was something I figured out as well. Never heard of those before though.... tried to understand the colour codes but haven't figured it out yet though. Figured out that the middle colour is the multiply and the first two are the digits.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also tell me how to figure out the voltage rating? As I understand it that should be in the color coding, but the calculators I tested didn't work with the color code, the gold and silver stripes proved problematic.

Comment: From what I found out of c5. Brown = 1, black = 0, multiply of black is 10 which would mean 10pF. Though, I can't figure out those last two colours which are gold and silver I guess

Comment: Yup, that's gold and silver. One band is for the precision and one for the voltage rating, I guess.

Comment: precision = tolerance...

Comment: I don't think the voltage rating is in there, though some US standard parts did that. Those parts look more like Japanese standard parts. It's more likely to be the temperature coefficient, which is not too important in your application (no tuned circuits).

Comment: According to [this](http://elektronik-kurs.net/elektrotechnik/farbcodierung-von-kondensatoren/) the fourth ring is tolerance and the fifth is the voltage rating.