# Modern equivalent for this 1980's capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

I'm trying to repair an old PC Engine game console and one of the missing components is a capacitor that looks just like a resistor. I'm not familiar with these and don't know how to read the colour bands or what a suitable modern equivalent might be. It's C137 in the picture, can anyone help? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: +1 for a decent photo. I can't help with the markings.

Comment: you sure it is a capacitor?  there could be a mod record (somewhere) stating "C137 to be fitted with a 1k resistor, MELF".  Where possible modifications will make use of available pads as it provides a more resilient connection and less mod time -  NOTE: I am not saying that in this instance it is a 1k resistor, this was just a example

Comment: Maybe it is just the same code like with resistors? 22 * 10^2 = 2.2nF?

Comment: C121 and 125 look like a capacitors, C137 looks so much like a MELF resistor, so much like the other Rs next to it, it's difficult to imagine it to be anything else.

Comment: I don't believe it's a resistor from multi-meter testing, all the R components in the same row give a resistance reading. Unfortunately, I don't have a way to measure capacitance. In case anyone was wondering, there are 2 of these on the motherboard so I'm able to test the one that's not missing.

Comment: Which PC Engine model exactly? Do you have a service manual?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's the later motherboard revision of the original white Japanese model. I haven't managed to find any service manuals for it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the color code (assuming all three bands are red and assuming it's a cap from the designator on the PCB), that's a 2.2nF MELF capacitor.

See also the photo in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/264464/what-is-the-type-of-these-caps/264474#264474) question which shows some similar leaded parts.

The similarity of body color to the resistors is a bit disconcerting though, I suspect it might not actually be a capacitor, but there is no way to be sure without more information (or by measuring a good one).

Comment: It's really hard to tell if it's red red red or red red brown, but I agree it's more of a concern whether it's actually a capacitor. I think I might break down and buy a LCR meter as I'm getting nowhere with my basic multimeter.

Comment: @Prateek Desoldering it and trying to measure resistance should help. If it's still intact, and it's a capacitor, it will show open-circuit. If it's a resistor it'll show what its proper value is. Even using an LCR meter might not work with it still all connected in the circuit like that.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Brown-Red-Red  Confirmed on IRfanview  1.2nF  SMD eqiv 2010 or less
[image]

Comment: I managed to get hold of a capacitance meter and the reading was 300pF. My assumption was that the bands are read from large to small which would indicate 220pF so it's not far off.

Comment: Or Orange Red Brown 320 pF

Comment: Yes, that's definitely a possibility. I might try my luck with a 300 or 330 ceramic as a replacement.

Comment: Probably an NPO cap